# Android Studio Java con Firebase

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Buenas Noches Estimados.

Estoy desarrollando un app para un trabajo universitario, lamentablemente me encuentro trabado con el mismo ya que no estoy pudiendo lograr que la app escriba datos en la base de datos, mucho menos traerlos. Les comparto el código de una activity en el cual el usuario ingresa datos en un EditText, donde dichos datos tienen que ser cargados en la colección "usuarios", la app no presenta ningun error pero dichos datos nunca son cargados en la base de datos.

public class Registro extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText nom,ap,dni,mail,key;
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro);
}

public void registrar(View v)
{
    nom=findViewById(R.id.idNombre);
    ap=findViewById(R.id.idApellido);
    dni=findViewById(R.id.idDni);
    mail=findViewById(R.id.idMail);
    key=findViewById(R.id.idKey);

    String nombre = nom.getText().toString();
    String apellido = ap.getText().toString();
    String dn = dni.getText().toString();
    String correo = mail.getText().toString();
    String clave = key.getText().toString();

    Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
    user.put("nombre", nombre);
    user.put("apellido", apellido);
    user.put("email", correo);
    user.put("dni", dn);
    user.put("password", clave);

    db.collection("usuarios")
            .add(user)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Se ha registrado correctamente: " + documentReference.getId());
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Error al cargar usuario", e);
                }
            });

    System.exit(1);
}
```

Los comandos que use acá son los que me sugiere Android Studio como guía para escribir en FireBase pero no esta funcionando. Cabe aclarar que el proyecto de Android Studio ya esta conectado y sincronizado con mi FireBase Obviamente debe haber algo que me falta pero al estar aprendiendo con esto tengo 0 experiencia. Seguro algún programador más experimentado lo va a deducir rápidamente.

Muchas Gracias

---

les comparto lo que me figura, el problema sigue estando, debería ser fácil de resolver ya que estoy tratando de usar el mismo ejemplo que propone Android Studio!. No estoy inventando un código muy complejo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola namoprogrma, bienvenido, te recomiendo hacer el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!.

Comment: ¿Revisaste el LogCat para saber que falla?

Comment: Si vas a desarrollar en Android el uso del LogCat es esencial, de otra forma vas a tardar en solucionar un problema. ¿Que error se muestra en el LogCat?

Answer (score 0):

te sugiero que crees un constructor con getters y setters para una mejor obtención de los datos

por ejemplo así`

public class Usuario {

```
String nombre,apellido ,dni, correo;
private long timestampRegistro;



public Usuario() {
}

public Usuario(String nombre, String apellido, String correo, String dni, long timestampRegistro) {
    
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido
    this.correo = correo;
    this.dni = dni;
    this.timestampRegistro = timestampRegistro;
}



public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}


public String getCorreo() {
    return correo;
}

public String getDni() {
    return dni;
}



public long getTimestampRegistro() {
    return timestampRegistro;
}
```

}`

Comment: Hola Mateo, gracias por tu aporte, te sugiero que edites tu respuesta, y le agregues las partes esparcidas por las otras respuestas (que quede todo en una sola), de esa manera evitarás los votos negativos y el cierre de tu pregunta.

Comment: hola.. tu respuesta debe ser una sola, completa, y que resuelva el problema.. aca hay un monton de codigo que no se que tiene que ver... arregla eso!!! usa el boton [edit] y edita la respuesta...

Answer (score -1):

Luego que tengas eso en una clase de java vamos a crear en otra clase los métodos para registrar al usuario y guardar sus datos en la base de datos de esta manera

MÉTODO PARA REGISTRAR AL USUARIO:

```
public static void registrarUsuario(String nombre, String correo, String contrasenia){

    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(correo,contrasenia)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        guardarUsuarioEnDatabase(nombre,correo);
                    }else{
                       
                        if (activity!=null){
                            
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "Algo a salido mal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

MÉTODO PARA GUARDAR DATOS EN LA BASE DE DATOS CON EL CONSTRUCTOR ANTERIOMENTE CREADO

```
private static void guardarUsuarioEnDatabase(String nombre, String correo){

    try {

        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();
        long timestampRegistro = firebaseUser.getMetadata().getCreationTimestamp();
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario(uid,nombre,correo,timestampRegistro);
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(FirebaseConstants.USERS)
                .document(uid)
                .set(usuario, SetOptions.merge())
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {


                        if (activity!=null ){
                            

                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                Intent intent =  new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                activity.startActivity(intent);
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(activity, "Algo ha salido mal a la hora de intentar guardar tus datos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        }

                    }
                });

    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        e.getCause();
    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Por último en tu código has estos cambios

```
EditText nom,ap,dni,mail,key;
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro);

    nom=findViewById(R.id.idNombre);
    ap=findViewById(R.id.idApellido);
    dni=findViewById(R.id.idDni);
    mail=findViewById(R.id.idMail);
    key=findViewById(R.id.idKey);



}

public void registrar(View v)
{
```

////registro controller le llamé a la clase donde creamos los dos métodos anteriores pero le puedes poner como quiera

```
RegistroController.registrarUsuario(getNombre(),getCorreo(),getContrasenia());

    

    

   
}







public String getNombre() {
        return nom.getText().toString();
    }

    public String getCorreo() {
        return mail.getText().toString();
    }

    public String getContrasenia() {
        return key.getText().toString();
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return  ape.getText().toString();
    }

    public String getDni() {
        return dni.getText().toString();
    }
```

Comment: No pongas tu respuesta en varias publicaciones. Si es muy larga, quizá estés dando información demás.

Comment: ¿Para que son estos cambios?, revisar [answer].